# set_value и динамическое добавление элементов формы

Tags: php, codigniter

Как правильно и не громоздко в коде занести в `value` значение из `set_value();`

Есть темплейт формы, далее я с помощью js клонирую данный темплейт и создаю динамически. После отправки запроса нужно чтобы все динамически созданные блоки остались и в `value` занеслись значения из `set_value`. Если прописывать в каждом `value` маркер и потом его заменять на значение из `set_value`, то получается многоватово кода. Есть ли какое то другое решение более удобное?

```
$depFormTemplate ='<div class="for-clone row" data-form-index="%k">
        <div class="col l3 m6 s12">
            <input type="text" name="department[%k][name]" placeholder="Department Name" value="%name">
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 m6 s12">
            <input type="text" name="department[%k][manager]" placeholder="Who is Boss?" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 m6 s12">
            <input type="text" name="department[%k][work_time]" placeholder="Working time" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 m6 s12">
            <div class="grouped">
                <input type="checkbox" name="department[%k][holidays]" class="filled-in" id="holidays" name="public_days" />
                <label for="holidays">Public Holidays / free days</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

<?php
if($this->input->post('department')){
    foreach($this->input->post('department') as $key => $dep){
        echo str_replace(
            array('%k', '%name'),
            array($key, set_value('department['.$key.'][name]')),
            $depFormTemplate
        );
    }
}else{
    echo str_replace(
            array('%k', '%name'),
            array(0, ''),
            $depFormTemplate
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, если используете jQuery, поставить и воспользоваться простой библиотекой, которая подойдет для вашей задачи

https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender

Comment: Спасибо.Надо будет изучить данную библиотеку!

Comment: Она очень простая, разберетесь

Comment: Правда не совсем представляю как  js-ом можно заполнить value после реквеста!

Comment: Набросал пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpGMO

Comment: Изначально при инициализации json с данными можно получить ajax запросом

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать